# Haskell QuickCheck Unique Random Number Generation

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

Does anyone know exactly how to define a generator in Haskell using QuickCheck such that chosen elements are picked only ONCE?

I've gotten as far as realizing that I might need a "Gen (Maybe Positive)" generator, but of course that will generate number with repetition. I want it so that the numbers chosen are picked without repetition. In the instance when a number is returned I want Just  returned and in the instance where the randoms are all exhausted I want Gen Nothing returned.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Look at the [definition of `Gen`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.4.1.1/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html). There's no way for it to carry any state about what has been picked so far. Given the same random generator and size limit it must always generate the same result. You *can* however write a `Eq a => Gen [a]` that generates a *list* of values with no repetitions. A simple (but somewhat naive) one would be something like this.

```
uniques :: Eq a => Gen a -> Gen [a]
uniques gen = fmap nub $ listOf gen
```

Comment: The xorshift random generator has no repetitions by design. You could try it. (the statement above holds for the first 2^64 or so numbers.

Comment: Hrm. I thought that it might be possible to pick a different generator each time using CoArbitrary (somehow?) with the range restricted/constrained

Answer (score 3):

QuickCheck is generally for randomized testing, not exhaustive testing. There are a few great libraries that *do* handle exhaustive testing -- look at [smallcheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/smallcheck) and [lazysmallcheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lazysmallcheck).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `permutations` (in module `Data.List`) for this.

Here is the function signature for `permutations`:

`permutations :: [a] -> [[a]]`

As you can see, it returns a list of lists.  Here is a little example (using GHCi 7.0.4):

`> permutations [1..3]

[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,1],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[1,3,2]]`

So you could do something like:

`prop_unique_elements = forAll (elements (permutations [1..3])) $ \x -> foo == bar`

I haven't tested that so it will need some massaging, but I hope it conveys the point clearly.  Good luck.

Comment: I don't think forall does what you think it does.

Comment: @sclv What do I think it does?  I always thought it was declaring universal quantification for the generator over the predicate.  :)  It  obviously doesn't exhaustively run each permutation once, but each result from the generator will be a list with unique elements, as the questions asks.

Comment: Then we just have different readings of the question -- I read it as asking for exhaustive testing -- i.e. picking a distinct element for each test, not as asking for a generator that produced lists of distinct elements for each test, but could potentially produce the same list on different tests.